# CLI tool to format XML files keeping empty lines and comments

Tags: xml, linux, format, command-line-interface, pretty-print

Is there any CLI tool for Linux which formats XML files keeping any empty lines and comments? I have tried `xmllint`, `tidy` and `xmlstarlet`, but all seem to focus completely cleaning XML files rather than just indentation and spacing.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [su] or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. Linters, code formators, and co are definitely programming related.

Comment: This is a request for a CLI tool, and therefore off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `xmlindent`. It has several options like `-nbe` and `-nba` and others that configure the handling of spaces before and after.

Given an XML input of

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Response>
  <TroubleResponse>
    <Check>
      <DStatus>
        <GID>123456789</GID>
        <FLAG/>
      </DStatus>
    </Check>
    <RAM>
      <Details>
        <RAMID>5555777788
        </RAMID>
      </Details>
    </RAM>
    <RAM>
      <Details>
        <RAMID>
            5555777788</RAMID>
      </Details>
    </RAM>
  </TroubleResponse>
</Response>
```

The output can be configured with the following options (an excerpt):

```
-t     Use tabs instead of spaces
-nas   Suppress newline after start-tag
-nae   Suppress newline after end-tag
-nbs   Suppress newline before start-tag
-nbe   Suppress newline before end-tag
-f     Force newline on elements without children
```

So `xmlindent -f` and `xmlindent -nba` would produce the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Response>
    <TroubleResponse>
        <Check>
            <DStatus>
                <GID>123456789       <!-- Change -->
                </GID>
                <FLAG/>
            </DStatus>
        </Check>
        <RAM>
            <Details>
                <RAMID>5555777788
                </RAMID>
            </Details>
        </RAM>
        <RAM>
            <Details>
                <RAMID>             <!-- Change -->
                    5555777788
                </RAMID>
            </Details>
        </RAM>
    </TroubleResponse>
</Response>
```

And `xmlindent -nbe` would produce the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Response>
    <TroubleResponse>
        <Check>
            <DStatus>
                <GID>123456789</GID>
                <FLAG/>
            </DStatus>
        </Check>
        <RAM>
            <Details>
                <RAMID>5555777788
                </RAMID>
            </Details>
        </RAM>
        <RAM>
            <Details>
                <RAMID>                  <!-- Change -->
                5555777788</RAMID>
            </Details>
        </RAM>
    </TroubleResponse>
</Response>
```

`xmlindent` is not perfect as it does not seem to always realize the expected outcome, but it can be somewhat configured.

Comment: Thank you very much. `xmlindent -nbe` does what I want.

Comment: I had to build `xmlindent` for MacOS, which required hacks to the build - I used `cmake` - once I get rid of local idiosyncrasies, I'll post a PR.